# Javascript declarar variaveis fora da função

Tags: javascript, html, input, variáveis

Eu só quero a soma desses dois números, funciona quando eu declaro as variáveis dentro da função, por que não está funcionando assim? Estou recebendo **NaN**.

```
<form>
    <input type="number" id="num1">
    <input type="number" id="num2">
    <input type="button" value="oi" onclick="calpp()">
</form>
<script>
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value, 10);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value, 10);

    function calpp(){
        alert(x+y);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Favor reescrever a sua pergunta em português, já que aqui é o stackoverflow português.

Comment: E porque você quer atribuir os valores fora da função?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é a sequência de execução do JavaScript.

Neste seu código, quando o navegador carrega e processa seu HTML, ele coloca na tela os 2 inputs, e em seguida processa a tag script e executa o código que está lá dentro.

Neste momento, ele já pega o conteúdo dos inputs e armazena nas variáveis, porém a página acabou de carregar e o usuário ainda não fez nenhuma interação, logo os campos estão vazios, então ele converte "vazio" para inteiro e armazena nas variáveis x e y.

Quando o usuário clica no botão, ele apenas recupera esses valores que já estão fixos como inválidos (pois foi processado no carregamento da página) e o cálculo dá errado.

Você consegue perceber isso se já atribuir um valor inicial nos inputs:

```js
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value, 10);
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value, 10);

  function calpp(){
      alert(x+y);
  }
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="number" id="num1" value="5">
    <input type="number" id="num2" value="3">
    <input type="button" value="oi" onclick="calpp()">
</form>
```

Com os valores iniciais seu código funciona, mas se o usuário altera ele vai ficar para sempre com os valores iniciais pois as linhas que recupera os valores dos inputs e salva nas variáveis já foi executado quando a página foi carregada.

Por isso que quando você move para dentro da função dá certo! Quando está dentro da função e você clica no botão, os valores são recuperados na hora do input, portanto o valor que está digitado lá naquele momento.

É importante entender esse fluxo de execução do HTML, JavaScript e CSS para evitar esse tipo de situação.

Por fim, seu código com a correção:

```js
// Podemos até declarar as variáveis fora da função
var x;
var y;

function calpp(){
  // Mas devemos sempre recuperar os dados do estado atual da aplicação
  x = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value, 10);
  y = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value, 10);
  
  // E por fim exibi-los
  alert(x+y);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="number" id="num1">
    <input type="number" id="num2">
    <input type="button" value="oi" onclick="calpp()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Isto é uma questão de ordem de execução no Javascript. Pode declarar as variáveis fora e pegar o valor dentro da função e fazer o parser como mostrado:

```js
var x = document.getElementById('num1');
var y = document.getElementById('num2');

function calpp() {
  var a = parseInt(x.value, 10);
  var b = parseInt(y.value, 10);
  
  console.log(`Valor de A: ${a} - Tipo: ${typeof a}`);
  console.log(`Valor de B: ${b} - Tipo: ${typeof b}`);
  console.log(`Soma: ${a + b}`);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" id="num1">
  <input type="number" id="num2">
  <input type="button" value="oi" onclick="calpp()">
</form>
```

Comment: Na verdade acredito que não é questão de escopo o real problema, e sim o fluxo de execução do JavaScript

Comment: Concordo com o @DiegoMarques, acho que embora o escopo seja o que muda o funcionamento do código, o problema real está na ordem das chamadas. Acho que essa resposta pode ser prejudicial para iniciantes e deveria ser editada.

Comment: @DiegoMarques e Lucas Espindola. Sim, sim, me faltou a palavra correta ali no momento ontem, mas, vocês definiram exatamente o que queria dizer, ordem de execução do Javascript. Post Editado, muito obrigado à ambos!