# como ultilizar valores de uma variavel em varias funcoes diferentes, em javascript,

Tags: javascript, funções, variáveis

````
function CalcularSoma(valor1, valor2, soma) {
    var valor1 = document.getElementById("formValor1").value;
    var valor2 = document.getElementById("formValor2").value;
    var soma;
    soma = parseInt(valor1) + parseInt(valor2);
    document.getElementById("formResultado").value = soma;
}
function CalcularMult(valor1, valor2, mult) {
    var valor1 = document.getElementById("formValor1").value;
    var valor2 = document.getElementById("formValor2").value;
    var mult = (valor1 * valor2);
    document.getElementById("formResultado").value = mult;
}
function CalcularDiv(valor1, valor2, div) {
    var valor1 = document.getElementById("formValor1").value;
    var valor2 = document.getElementById("formValor2").value;
    var div = (valor1 / valor2);
    document.getElementById("formResultado").value = div;
}
function CalcularSub(valor1, valor2, sub) {
    var valor1 = document.getElementById("formValor1").value;
    var valor2 = document.getElementById("formValor2").value;
    var sub = (valor1 - valor2);
    document.getElementById("formResultado").value = sub;
}```
````

Comment: Basta declarar a variável fora da função.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 O problema de declarar fora da função é acontecer [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363886/112052) (e não dá pra saber se vai ocorrer porque a pergunta não dá mais detalhes)

Comment: Podes explicar melhor a questão? não tenho a certeza do que procuras resolver.

Comment: Como você está chamando estas funções, Marcelo?

Comment: ultilizando o evento onclick, porem ao tentar realmente evitar a repeticao do codigo criando a variavel em todas as funcoes o coddigo da erro, gostaria de entender melhor como conseguir removelas e ficar um codigo mais visivel simplemente isso, estou iniciando agora tenho pouco conhecimento na linguagem em si.

Comment: @sergio queria saber se tem uma forma de declarar essas variaveis fora da funcao e poder ultilizala em outras funcoes, para nao ficar repetindo em toda funcao as mesmas variaveis valor1 e valor2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu alteraria as funções pra receber diretamente o valor, além de mudar um monte de outras coisas no teu código:

```
function calcularSoma(valor1, valor2) {
    let soma = valor1 + valor2;
    return soma;
}
function calcularMult(valor1, valor2) {
    let mult = (valor1 * valor2);
    return mult;
}
function calcularDiv(valor1, valor2) {
    let div = (valor1 / valor2);
    return div;
}
function calcularSub(valor1, valor2, sub) {
    let sub = (valor1 - valor2);
    return sub;
}
```

Aí você usaria essas funções assim:

```
let valor1 = document.getElementById("formValor1").value;
let valor2 = document.getElementById("formValor2").value;

document.getElementById("formResultado1").value = calcularSoma(valor1, valor2);
document.getElementById("formResultado2").value = calcularMult(valor1, valor2);
document.getElementById("formResultado3").value = calcularDiv(valor1, valor2);
document.getElementById("formResultado4").value = calcularSub(valor1, valor2, sub);
```

Isso tudo porque usar variáveis globais gera erros de carregamento e de processamento inesperados, o que eu acredito que não seja o teu intuito, além de que criar uma função que acessa um elemento do DOM, lê seu valor, executa algo e depois modifica outro elemento do DOM não é, exatamente, fácil de ler. Se você, por exemplo, fosse inserir essa função em um evento `onclick`, eute indicaria criar uma função pra executar essa alteração, como:

```
function exibeSoma(){
    let valor1 = document.getElementById("formValor1").value;
    let valor2 = document.getElementById("formValor2").value;
    document.getElementById("formResultado").value = calcularSoma(valor1, valor2);
}
```

Vê como fica mais legível, além de facilitar a manutenção?

Comment: Queria saber o motivo da resposta ter sido negativada :/

Comment: Não sei também, eu achei boa!

Comment: realmete bem mais legivel, muito obrigado  pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Seria melhor estruturares o código de uma maneira diferente. Repara que as linhas:

`var valor1 = document.getElementById("formValor1").value;
 var valor2 = document.getElementById("formValor2").value;`

Estão a ser repetidas em todas as funções. Seria mais simples separares essas linhas para fora das funções. A tua função deve ter um só propósito, por exemplo, somar os números. No teu caso estás a usar a função para receber o input e processar os dados, tenta separar melhor essas responsabilidades quando constróis a função, assim não vais repetir código e ter códigos enormes desnecessários.